# What are the uses of "totality"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Often I find myself wanting to use 'totality' in a sentence that would otherwise work with 'total'. What are the correct usages of 'totality' given that both nouns describing the sum or completeness of something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**totality** means the whole of something, and from what I've seen it describe, it is usually something complex: In gvt., "the *totality* of their current policies", in Psych: "the *totality* of the human mind", book: "Preface to *Totality* and Infinity", "the totality of dispositions to verbal behavior" It may carry a connotation of something beyond numbers, something *immeasurable.*

Total means the whole number or amount of something. It could be as small as the total number of students, a total scored, grand total of winnings. It also means completeness; one can say "the total sum of our knowledge".

the difference may come down to the complexity which is connoted in *totality* rather than *total*.

Answer (score 2):

A common use of *totality* is in astronomy.  Search (CTL F) this wikipedia article for both *total* and *totality* and you'll get a good feel for how the words are used.         [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse)    Also, *total* is at least 3 different parts of speech.  *Totality* is a noun that comes in handy when you need to use both words with precision.